# How to generate a JWT for a Cloud Function HTTP trigger?

Tags: java, jwt, google-cloud-functions

What I'm trying to do is generate a JWT for calling the HTTP trigger on a GCP Cloud Function I've deployed.
I've already deployed my function with 'allUsers' and verified it works, but I want it to be more secure, so I need to attach a JWT to my HTTP request.
I'm following [this code](https://gist.github.com/tylertreat/b2f17f9d55ae55002b218a7b4cf778b5) and the following snippets are mostly from that. 
I think I am close, but not quite there yet. In all of the samples etc below I've changed my project name to PROJECT_NAME.

First I created a service account named testharness-sa and downloaded its key file. I have an env var GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to that file when I run my tests. Then I ran the following command:

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding gopubsub \
  --member='serviceAccount:testharness-sa@PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com' \
  --role='roles/cloudfunctions.invoker'
```

This gave me a confirmation by listing all the current bindings on my cloud function, including testharness-sa.

The core of my code is this:

```java
    private String getSignedJwt() {
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
                .getApplicationDefault()
                .createScoped(Collections.singleton(IAM_SCOPE));
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) credentials.getPrivateKey();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, privateKey);
        return JWT.create()
                .withKeyId(credentials.getPrivateKeyId())
                .withIssuer(credentials.getClientEmail())
                .withSubject(credentials.getClientEmail())
                .withAudience(OAUTH_TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
                .withIssuedAt(new Date(now))
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(now + EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_MILLIS))
                .withClaim("target_audience", clientId)
                .sign(algorithm);
    }
```

This gives me a signed JWT. As I understand things, this is used to call GCP to get me a final JWT I can use to call my cloud function.

Once I generate the signed JWT I use it like this:

```java
        String jwt = getSignedJwt();
        final GenericData tokenRequest = new GenericData()
                .set("grant_type", JWT_BEARER_TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE)
                .set("assertion", jwt);
        final UrlEncodedContent content = new UrlEncodedContent(tokenRequest);

        final HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();

        final HttpRequest request = requestFactory
                .buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(OAUTH_TOKEN_URI), content)
                .setParser(new JsonObjectParser(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()));

        HttpResponse response = request.execute();
...
```

So it gets the signed JWT and makes up a request to get the final JWT and then... fails. The error is "Invalid JWT: Failed audience check"
It looks like I have a bad parameter, so let's look at my parameters (they are actually constants, not parameters):

```java
    private static final String IAM_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam";
    //"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";
    private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN_URI = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
    //"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN_AUDIENCE = "https://us-central1-PROJECT_NAME.cloudfunctions.net/gopubsub";
    //"https://www.googleapis.com/token";
    private static final String JWT_BEARER_TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";
    private static final long EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 3600 * 1000L;
```

I've added other variants as comments against the constants.

Based on the error message it looks like the audience value I'm using is wrong. 
[This page](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication) suggests the audience should be the service account email, and I think I've seen elsewhere that it ought to be the URL of the cloud function, but neither of those work for me.

I do know this can work because I can issue this command:

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```

which gives me the final JWT (as long as I have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing at my json file).
I can paste that JWT into a curl command and invoke the HTTP trigger successfully, and if I leave the JWT out it fails, so I know the JWT is being checked.
But so far I don't know how to do the equivalent of gcloud auth print-identity-token from my Java code.
Anyone know?

Comment: Have you tried generating the jwt without the IAM_SCOPE as shown in the sample from this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?_gac=1.204745380.1582892387.EAIaIQobChMIsri30Z305wIVTtTeCh35Sw4REAAYASAAEgJRUPD_BwE&_ga=2.131851911.98076515.1585562385-311348016.1585748777#jwt-auth)?

Comment: I have now :) and yes, it doesn't seem to make any difference, however I found the problem wasn't related to scope. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer was not related to scope, despite the error message. It is actually related to the `clientId` value I was passing (and didn't really mention in my question, though it is there in the code). I was using a value I found in the service account json file, a really long string of digits. That was the problem. It needed to be the URL of my HTTP trigger. So these are the constants I ended up with:

```
    private static final String IAM_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";
    private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN_URI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN_AUDIENCE = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    private static final String JWT_BEARER_TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";
    private static final long EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 3600 * 1000L;
```

In fact it still works if I remove all references to `IAM_SCOPE`, so I conclude that doesn't matter. The piece of code that pulls it together now looks like this:

```java
        return JWT.create()
                .withKeyId(credentials.getPrivateKeyId())
                .withIssuer(credentials.getClientEmail())
                .withSubject(credentials.getClientEmail())
                .withAudience(OAUTH_TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
                .withIssuedAt(new Date(now))
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(now + EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_MILLIS))
                .withClaim("target_audience", targetURL)
                .sign(algorithm);
```

Specifically the change is the `withClaim()` call which now contains the URL I want to call. With that in place the code returns the JWT I was hoping for and which does, in fact, work when I call the secured HTTP trigger URL. Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: I don't quite understand how your code is compiling. `GoogleCredentials` are missing several of the methods you're using. I suspect you made a find/replace in your question from `GoogleCredential` (which is now deprecated) to `GoogleCredentials`.